# Is the following a Folner Sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: group-theory, amenability

Just out of curiosity is the following a folner sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$

$$\left\{\frac{2m+1}{2n}:m\in\mathbb{Z},n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\neq 0},n<d\right\}\cup\left\{\frac{j}{2k+1}:j,k\in\mathbb{Z},k<d^d\right\}$$

Folner sequences of $A=\mathbb{Q}$ are defined by the condition

$$\lim_{d\to\infty}\frac{|gA_d\Delta A_d|}{|A_d|}=0$$

Where for group $G$ that acts on $A$, $g\in G$ and $\left\{A_d\right\}_{d\in\mathbb{N}}$ are a sequence of finite subsets of $A$.

Comment: To be precise, you need to say that the condition holds for all $g$. And also, since $\mathbf{Q}$ is meant as additive, you should write $g+A_d$ instead of $gA_d$.

Comment: Your subsets are infinite as there's no bound on $j$, no (negative) lower bound on $n,k$...